# How to use asterisks to make a graph with existing data in a file?

Tags: java, file, graph, nested-loops

I have a two part assignment and I am having trouble with the second part.

The first part of the assignment was to ask the user their weekly budget for 4 weeks and that information was to be saved to a file named budget.txt. If you need to see it I can copy and paste the code for you.

Output looks like this:

```
Week 1 Budget: 230.99  
Week 2 Budget: 800.00  
Week 3 Budget: 125.00  
Week 4 Budget: 1245.18
```

The second part of the assignment(the part I'm having trouble with) is to read the data the user input and make an asterisk graph from the information. Each asterisk is supposed to represent $100. The output of this second program I am working on should be like this(according to the information in the example above):

```
Week 1 Budget: **  
Week 2 Budget: ********  
Week 3 Budget: *  
Week 4 Budget: ************
```

How do I establish the connection that each asterisk represents $100 and have it output correctly? Here is my current code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    float budget;

    File file = new File("budget.txt");
    if (!file.exists())
    {
        System.out.println("The file budget.txt is not found.");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

    while (inputFile.hasNext())
    {
        //Read a value from the file.
        budget = inputFile.nextFloat();

        for(int c=0; c <= 3; c++)
        {
            System.out.print("\nBudget for week " + (c +1) + ":");

            for(int k=0; k<=budget/100; k++) 
            {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();

        inputFile.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: When you use the values in your example, what output do you get?

Comment: Budget for week 1:**********  
Budget for week 2:**********  
Budget for week 3:**********  
Budget for week 4:**********

Comment: Do a manual tracing of your program: If the `k` loop is iterated as many times as `budget/100`, where does this `budget` value come from?

Comment: On the first program that saved the user input to the file budget.txt, "budget" is the float variable that was being typed by the user for the 4 weeks.

Comment: @Jayne Doe: Yes, but I didn't mean the first program. Where is the _immediate_ place where this variable is loaded before the `k` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the purpose of that internal for loop ?
`for(int c=0; c <= 3; c++)`

You don't need to use a for loop to print those asterisks, you can simple use `String.format`

```
int week = 1;
        while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
            // Read a value from the file.
            budget = inputFile.nextFloat();

            System.out.print("\nBudget for week " + week++ + ":");
            System.out.println(String.format("%" + (budget / 100) + "s", "").replaceAll(" ", "*"));

        }
```

Comment: The purpose was to create the "Week 1 Budget:", "Week 2 Budget:", "Week 3 Budget", "Week 4 Budget" in front of where the asterisks would be. I was really just overthinking the whole assignment and making it so much more complicated than it needed to be. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @JayneDoe Ok, don't forget to choose a right answer

Answer (score 0):

```
int c = 1;
while (inputFile.hasNext())
{
    budget = inputFile.nextFloat();
    System.out.print("\nBudget for week " + c + ":");

        for(int k=1; k<budget/100; k++) 
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
    }
    c++;
    System.out.println();
}
inputFile.close();
```